Random Forest and Cross Validation
I want to perform a random forest model using cross validation technique.
First I use hyperparameter tuning to tune my model,
Secondly, I perform a manual cross-valiadation split using KFold=10 to train the data,
Finally, I choose the best model from the cross-validation training data with the highest score.
I save the model and then I test the model on test set, which the model has not seen before.
Then I print out the results
I am not sure if I am doing the right thing.
Can you kindly check the code and correct me where I am wrong?
# 1
def random_forest_model(X_train, y_train, seed=42):
    # Set the seed for reproducibility
    np.random.seed(seed)

    # Number of trees in random forest
    n_estimators = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start=2, stop=128, num=120)]  # Adjusted for the number of rows
    # Number of features to consider at every split
    max_features = ['sqrt', 'log2', 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, None]
    # Maximum number of levels in tree
    max_depth = [5, 6, 7, 8, None]  # Removed 60 and 100 considering the data size
    # Minimum number of samples required to split a node
    min_samples_split = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]  # Adjusted for a small dataset
    # Minimum number of samples required at each leaf node
    min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]  # Adjusted for a small dataset
    # Method of selecting samples for training each tree
    bootstrap = [True, False]


    # Create the param grid
    param_grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
                  'max_features': max_features,
                  'max_depth': max_depth,
                  'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
                  'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf,
                  'bootstrap': bootstrap}

    # Initialize the Random Forest Regressor model
    rf_Model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=seed)

    # Perform Randomized Search Cross Validation
    rf_RandomGrid = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=rf_Model, param_distributions=param_grid,
                                       cv=10, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1, n_iter=1000, random_state=seed) 
    rf_RandomGrid.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Get the best parameters from Randomized Search CV
    best_params = rf_RandomGrid.best_params_

    # Use the best parameters to train the final model
    best_rf_model = RandomForestRegressor(**best_params, random_state=seed, n_jobs=-1)

    return best_params, best_rf_model  # Return all two variables

#2 

# Load training data from Excel file
train_data = pd.read_excel('/home/jovyan/Desktop/Random_forest/Data/2018/Crops_and_Nutrients_2018_Original/Barley_Cu_grain_data.xlsx')

# Load test data from Excel file
test_data = pd.read_excel('/home/jovyan/Desktop/Random_forest/Data/2017/Crops_and_Nutrients_2017_Original/Barley_Cu_grain_data.xlsx')

# Extract nutrient name from test data
nutrient_name = test_data.columns[0]


# Extract Crop name
crop_name = test_data.iloc[0, 2]

print("Cu_grain string:", nutrient_name, "Crop name:", crop_name)

# Select specific columns for training data
selected_columns_train = [ nutrient_name, "May_MCARI_mean", "November_PhRI_mean", "September_B8A_mean"]
# Select specific columns for test data
selected_columns_test =  [ nutrient_name,"May_MCARI_mean", "November_PhRI_mean", "September_B8A_mean"]


# Filter training data for Barley crop and select specific columns
train_data = train_data[selected_columns_train]

# Filter test data for Barley crop and select specific columns
test_data = test_data[selected_columns_test]

# Set pandas display options to show all columns
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

# Print null value counts for training data before dropping null values
print("Null value counts for each column in training data before dropping null values:")
print(train_data.isnull().sum())

# Print null value counts for test data before dropping null values
print("\nNull value counts for each column in test data before dropping null values:")
print(test_data.isnull().sum())


# Drop null values from the training data
train_data = train_data.dropna()

# Drop null values from the test data
test_data = test_data.dropna()

# Print the shape of training data after dropping null values
print("Shape of training data after dropping null values:", train_data.shape)

# Print the shape of test data after dropping null values
print("Shape of test data after dropping null values:", test_data.shape)

X_train_columns = train_data[selected_columns_train].drop(columns=[nutrient_name]).columns
X_train = train_data[selected_columns_train].drop(columns=[nutrient_name]).values
y_train = train_data[nutrient_name].values  # Assuming 'target_column' is the name of your target column

X_test_columns = test_data[selected_columns_test].drop(columns=[nutrient_name]).columns
X_test = test_data[selected_columns_test].drop(columns=[nutrient_name]).values
y_test = test_data[nutrient_name].values  # Assuming 'target_column' is the name of your target column

# Print the shape of training data
print("Shape of X_train:", X_train.shape)
print("Shape of y_train:", y_train.shape)

# Print the shape of test data
print("Shape of X_test:", X_test.shape)
print("Shape of y_test:", y_test.shape)

# 3

# Train Random Forest Model
best_params, best_rf_model = random_forest_model(X_train, y_train, seed=42)

seed=42

# Initialize variables for cross-validation
k = 10
kf_10 = KFold(n_splits=k, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
rmse_scores = []  # List to store RMSE scores for each fold
model_scores = []  # List to store trained models for each fold

# Perform cross-validation
for fold, (train_index, val_index) in enumerate(kf_10.split(X_train)):
    # Split data into train and validation sets for current fold
    X_train_CV, X_val_CV = X_train[train_index], X_train[val_index]
    y_train_CV, y_val_CV = y_train[train_index], y_train[val_index]
    
    # Fit the model on the training data for current fold
    best_rf_model.fit(X_train_CV, y_train_CV)
    
    # Predict on the validation set for current fold
    y_pred = best_rf_model.predict(X_val_CV)
    
    # Calculate RMSE for current fold and append to list
    rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_val_CV, y_pred))
    rmse_scores.append(rmse)
    
    # Store the trained model for current fold
    model_scores.append(best_rf_model)

# Print RMSE scores
print("RMSE Scores:", rmse_scores)

# Print the list of trained models
print("Trained Models:", model_scores)

# Find the best fold based on minimum RMSE
best_fold = min(range(len(rmse_scores)), key=rmse_scores.__getitem__)
best_model = model_scores[best_fold]

# Create folder to save the best model
folder_name = f"{crop_name}_{nutrient_name}"
model_folder = os.path.join(folder_name, "best_model")
if not os.path.exists(model_folder):
    os.makedirs(model_folder)

# Save the best model
model_filename = f"best_model_{crop_name}_{nutrient_name}.joblib"
model_path = os.path.join(model_folder, model_filename)
joblib.dump(best_model, model_path)

# Use the best model on the test set
y_pred_test = best_model.predict(X_test)
rmse_test = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred_test))

# Calculate evaluation metrics on test set
training_accuracy = best_model.score(X_train, y_train)
testing_accuracy = best_model.score(X_test, y_test)
mean_absolute_err = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred_test)
mean_squared_err = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred_test)
root_mean_squared_err = np.sqrt(mean_squared_err)
explained_var_score = explained_variance_score(y_test, y_pred_test)
r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred_test)

# Print evaluation metrics
print("Training Accuracy on training set using the model from the best fold is:", training_accuracy)
print("Testing Accuracy on test set using the model from the best fold is:", testing_accuracy)
print("Mean Absolute Error on test set using the model from the best fold is: %.3f" % mean_absolute_err)
print("Mean Squared Error on test set using the model from the best fold is: %.3f" % mean_squared_err)
print("Root Mean Squared Error on test set using the model from the best fold is: %.3f" % root_mean_squared_err)
print("Explained Variance Score on test set using the model from the best fold is: %.3f" % explained_var_score)
print("R-squared on test set using the model from the best fold: %.3f" % r2)

Results:
Fitting 10 folds for each of 1000 candidates, totalling 10000 fits
RMSE Scores: [1.2620720242791514, 2.315684496466628, 1.0255090254760533, 1.621527314310136, 0.8239058885392384, 2.508852211430445, 2.284719512386705, 1.6774232849059205, 2.166365889441688, 0.8286999731173564]
Trained Models: [RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=6, max_features='sqrt', min_samples_leaf=9,
                      min_samples_split=4, n_estimators=3, n_jobs=-1,
                      random_state=42), RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=6, max_features='sqrt', min_samples_leaf=9,
                      min_samples_split=4, n_estimators=3, n_jobs=-1,
                      random_state=42), RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=6, max_features='sqrt', min_samples_leaf=9,
                      min_samples_split=4, n_estimators=3, n_jobs=-1,
                      random_state=42), RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=6, max_features='sqrt', min_samples_leaf=9,
                      min_samples_split=4, n_estimators=3, n_jobs=-1,
                      random_state=42), RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=6, max_features='sqrt', min_samples_leaf=9,
                      min_samples_split=4, n_estimators=3, n_jobs=-1,
                      random_state=42), RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=6, max_features='sqrt', min_samples_leaf=9,
                      min_samples_split=4, n_estimators=3, n_jobs=-1,
                      random_state=42), RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=6, max_features='sqrt', min_samples_leaf=9,
                      min_samples_split=4, n_estimators=3, n_jobs=-1,
                      random_state=42), RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=6, max_features='sqrt', min_samples_leaf=9,
                      min_samples_split=4, n_estimators=3, n_jobs=-1,
                      random_state=42), RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=6, max_features='sqrt', min_samples_leaf=9,
                      min_samples_split=4, n_estimators=3, n_jobs=-1,
                      random_state=42), RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=6, max_features='sqrt', min_samples_leaf=9,
                      min_samples_split=4, n_estimators=3, n_jobs=-1,
                      random_state=42)]
Training Accuracy on training set using the model from the best fold is: 0.33641066977649203
Testing Accuracy on test set using the model from the best fold is: -0.47812039088749114
Mean Absolute Error on test set using the model from the best fold is: 1.296
Mean Squared Error on test set using the model from the best fold is: 2.745
Root Mean Squared Error on test set using the model from the best fold is: 1.657
Explained Variance Score on test set using the model from the best fold is: -0.149
R-squared on test set using the model from the best fold: -0.478


Random forests do not need explicit cross validation.  Check your process and fix it.
